# Retrieve data from database based on radio button value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to php and mysql so forgive me if I'm doing this completely wrong. I am making a printing balance application and the code below is a part of it.

```
$command="SELECT itemname FROM items";
$results = mysql_query($command);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            print "<input type='radio' name='itemtype' value='$value'>".$value."</input><br />";
    }
}
```

This here is supposedly the price printing form where the user chooses between SHORT BOND PAPER and LONG BOND PAPER (the column itemname from items). The options appear as radio buttons. It works but now I'm stuck with the issue of being able to fetch the price as inserted in their respective rows. Since the itemname and their price are all user-inputted into the database, I'm not supposed to declare their specific price into the code itself, and should be able to retrieve it from the database. I want to be able to get the prices based on the item chosen by the user once they click submit, because I'd need to do this to compute for the price of printing when multiplied with the number of pages later.

I think it's definitely possible but I'm not quite sure how. Theoretically, it would be along the lines of SELECT itemprice FROM items WHERE itemname = $value but ha, I don't think it works that way.

---

solution edit: here's the complete solution for reference. $compute is just a sample to test if it works while 5 is a sample number of pages that would be entered.

```
if ($command = mysql_query("SELECT `itemprice` FROM `items` WHERE `itemname` LIKE '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['itemtype']) . "'"))
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($command))
{
$compute = $row['itemprice'] * 5;
echo $compute;
}
}
else
{
echo (mysql_error ());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be something like that indeed.

```
SELECT itemprice FROM items WHERE itemname = $_POST['itemtype']
```

assuming that itemprice is the actuial colum of the price. HOwever, doing it like this, makes your code vulnerable to mysql injections. So before you contine, consider reading up a little.

Comment: Yes, I have the stuffs needed to deal with the mysql injection. Anyway, the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)" appears with your code. I was able to look up solutions online though and was able to fix it. Thank you so much for the reply. I knew I was getting close but was tired of going around in circles trying to figure it out. The guidance was greatly appreciated ^^